# Outdoor WiFi antenna

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

In the past I bought a long 20 meter USB cable as I wanted to charge my phone from a socket that was far away from my bed, however due to the length of the cable the electric did not travel far enough. I never found a solution to this problem.

Recently, I bought this outdoor WiFi antenna on the Wish website [here](https://www.wish.com/product/5d2838e8770395055c1a94a5?hide_login_modal=true), that is low power 30m.

Would I be able to just plug this into my laptop, or will I have problems because of the length of the cable and if so how can I resolve them?

Comment: Care to provide the specifications on this website since they are inaccessible on Wish?

Comment: Check the edited link, sorry about that.

Comment: Nowhere in that link is a length of 30m mentioned. The USB specification itself does not support 30m cable. I can not recommend ever going beyond 15m.

Comment: @Mast When I clicked the buy button I was given a length of cables, so I picked the 30m one. It must work if they are selling it...?

Comment: “It must work” If they’re selling it on Wish? Wish is not really known for the quality of the stuff they sell. BTW according to USB2.0 specifications, maximum cable length is about 5 meters. 20 meters will simply not work reliably.

Comment: just buy and report back

Comment: @StarCat True, but it has a bunch of good reviews, and if something was that broken I doubt they would sell it for so long. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @alecxs Will do!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "possibly, but it's a bad idea" and quite possibly a waste of your money.

As was mentioned in the comments, the USB specification only allows for around 5 meters. These specifications aren't set arbitrarily, there's a ton of electrical engineering work that goes into determining these. They also tend to have pretty generous slop in those specs, so I can't imagine that going 6x over the spec's max length is a good idea.

Even if it functions at all, you're likely to have compromised speed or reliability.

Also, consider that Wish.com is a reseller for the cheapest Chinese crap imaginable, and is filled with outright scams and lies.